# Puxar imagem do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou criando um site de receitas e queria mostrar a imagem que o usuário inseriu ao cadastrar. No meu banco de dados fiz duas tabelas, uma da receita e outra para o arquivo de imagem.

```
 CREATE TABLE Receita(
  idReceita INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  nome_Receita VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  preparo  TEXT NOT NULL,
  ingredientes text not null,
  usuario_idUsuario int,
  categoria_idCategoria int,
  dificuldade_idDificuldade int,
  PRIMARY KEY (idReceita)
); 


  cREATE TABLE `arquivo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `arquivo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

depois eu adiciono id da receita como chave estrangeira na tabela de arquivos e na hora de gravar no banco pelo php uso a função de last id. Só que não sei como fazer a relação das duas tabelas pra mostrar a imagem certa no meu site.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="" class="img-rounded">
            <?php
            $sql3 = "select idreceita From Receita where nome_receita= '" . $receita . "';";
            $result3 = $CONEXAO->query($sql3);
            $sql_busca = "select from arquivo where receita_idreceita = '" . $result3 . "';";
            $mostrar = mysqli_query($CONEXAO, $sql_busca);
            $qtd_arquivos = mysqli_num_rows($mostrar);
            while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar)){
               $arquivo = $dados['arquivo']; 
            ?>
            <img class="img-fluid col-md-2 img-thumbnail" src="upload/<?=$arquivo?>" width=500 height:300 />
            <?php }?>

</div>
```

Se puderem me ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que possa usar o [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Receita
       INNER JOIN arquivo
               ON arquivo.id = Receita.idReceita
WHERE  nome_receita = '" . $receita . "';
```

Então no final:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="" class="img-rounded">
            <?php
            $mostrar = mysqli_query($CONEXAO, "SELECT * FROM Receita INNER JOIN arquivo ON arquivo.id = Receita.idReceita WHERE nome_receita= '" . $receita . "';");
            while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar)){
               $arquivo = $dados['arquivo']; 
            ?>
            <img class="img-fluid col-md-2 img-thumbnail" src="upload/<?=$arquivo?>" width=500 height:300 />
            <?php }?>

</div>
```

---

Caso queira fazer dois `SELECT` distintos, como está a usar, você pode deve especificar o nome da coluna/index do array:

Ao invés de fazer (usando `$result3`):

```
$sql_busca = "select from arquivo where receita_idreceita = '" . $result3 . "';";
```

Você deve fazer (use `$result3["idreceita"]`):

```
$sql_busca = "select from arquivo where receita_idreceita = '" . $result3["idreceita"] . "';";
```

Dessa forma você está informando que o valor de `receita_idreceita` é o `$result3["idreceita"]` que será o `idreceita`. Se especificar apenas `$result3` você está informando uma array.